# Serial communication between c++ and arduino

Tags: c++, serial-communication

i need communicate with the arduino by using C++,i have tried this code for c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int j=5;
main()
{
 fstream arduino;
 arduino.open("/dev/ttyACM0",ios::in | ios::out);
 //Opening device file

 if(!arduino)
   cout<<"error";
 arduino<<2;
 arduino.clear();
 arduino>> j;
 cout <<j;
 arduino.close();
 return 0;
}
```

Arduino code:

```
      int p;
      void setup() 
      {
          pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
          Serial.begin(9600);
       }

       void loop() 
       {
           if(Serial.available())
           {
               p=Serial.read();
               if(p!=-1)
               {
                   Serial.write(1);
                   digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
                   delay(5000);
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                digitalWrite(13,LOW);
                delay(1000);
            } 
        }
```

So according to this code when ever c++ code runs the led of pin 13 on arduino sould glow for 5 seconds and cout should print 1. But instead the led is not glowing and cout is printing 5 which(see that initially j=5).I am using this program to test serial communication between c++ and arduino. But I don't know what's happening.Also do we require any any special library for serial communication? 
Is my code alright? 
Please help me out.

Comment: @MANDY: Make sure you are configuring the right baud rate, parity, flow control, etc. before running the C++ program.  For example, the `stty` utility can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

If `j` keeps its old value, it is likely that the attempt to read it is failing.  Try checking the stream state, and checking for possible error conditions.  For example:

```
if(arduino >> j)
    cout << "Value received: " << j << '\n';
else if(arduino.eof())
    cerr << "Premature EOF.\n";
else if(arduino.bad())
    cerr << "Attempt to read from device failed.\n";
else
    cerr << "Logical I/O error.\n";
```

Comment: sorry I am beginner in c++. I got error --"Premature EOF".How to correct this?

Comment: I don't know what's really going on, but I suspect that the Arduino device might be sending a single byte (or shorter than you PC's integer), and the PC requires at least `sizeof(int)` bytes (typically 4 bytes) to satisfy reading an to a variable of `int` type.  Another possible cause is that nothing is arriving at the PCs.  Try changing your input variable type to `char`, and see if reading to it succeeds.

Comment: i tried changing int to char but it is showing the same error.

Comment: @Paulo1205: Actually `arduino>> j;` is text parsing, not a binary read of `sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: OTOH -- and since I am not familiar with what the other end sends, and thus assuming it _could_ be binary data --, changing the data to `char` might be enough to rule out unexpected non-digit characters on input.

Comment: @MANDY, if you run `strace` on the PCs side, what do you get?

Comment: sorry I don't know about strace.